# How to pre-render map tiles

Tags: wms, ogc, wmts

I'm looking for a mechanism/mechanisms where by I can pre-render my own map tiles and then server them up to the client through OGC WMTS service. There are numerous ways I have searched on the web which say how to get the pre-rendered map tiles and hand them over to a client, but none of them is talking about first how to pre-render the tiles themselves and also how to invalidate the old tiles and update the tile cache with new tiles.

And in my case WMTS service is a must and I don't want to take help of a WMS service to fetch a big map image and chop that up into small tiles and hand it over to the end client for users to see that.

Comment: Please add the datasource from which you want to render the tiles.

Comment: Its just a big giant land base map with all the vector layers overlayed on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to render raster data then MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.com) can help you.

It produces WMTS conformant map tiles - and once you upload the rendered tile on a standard web server (like your company web) or any cloud hosting (such as Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage) your map will be available as OGC WMTS - and openable in ArcGIS, QGIS, OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc.

See:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5gFXvxWIHM&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PiQd1mO-S9QrCjqSn1v-ay&index=9